# TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

When I am trying to use the service in my componenet and declatring it in constructor , I am getting this error TypeError: Cannot set property stack of [object Object] which has only a getter

I have below my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginService } from '../../services/login.service'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'login-selector',
  templateUrl: './app/components/login/login.component.html',
})

export class LoginComponent  { 

    form:FormGroup;
    items:Object;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
        private loginService:LoginService){

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.form=this.formBuilder.group({
            userName:this.formBuilder.control(''),
            password:this.formBuilder.control(''),
            remember:this.formBuilder.control(''),
            textCaptcha:this.formBuilder.control('')
        });
    }

onSubmit(loginForm:FormGroup){
        this.loginService.getTestJson().subscribe(mediaItems => {
            this.items = mediaItems;
        });
    }
}
```

Service is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getTestJson(){
        return this.http.get('http://geo.groupkt.com/ip/172.217.3.14/json').map(response => {
            return response.json();
        });


    }

}
```

and app module ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';  
import { LoginService } from './services/login.service'; 

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,LoginComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:[LoginService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: The application is not running when i am defining Login Service in Components constryctor.

Answer (score 0):

import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http'; in app module ts 
and add it in NgModule imports

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you have ngModel in your Html, to do so, you need to be very careful.

You can't just use ngModel by itself in formGroup. It only works with formGroupName